# How to add to a button "jQuery confirm" for confirmation to work

Tags: jquery, button, confirm

Using the [module](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm) but after clicking "yes" nothing is sent. Explain, please.

```
 <form class="zaeb" action="" method="post" id="kek">
                    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?php echo $plan->id; ?>">
                    <button id="b12<?php echo $plan->id; ?>" type="submit" class="example2 btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" name="buy"><b>CLICK HERE TO PURCHASE</b></button>
```

jQuery:

```
                        $('button.example2').confirm({
title: 'Confirm!',
content: 'Simple confirm!',
buttons: {
    confirm: function () {
        $.alert('Confirmed!');
    },
    cancel: function () {
        $.alert('Canceled!');
    },
    somethingElse: {
        text: 'Something else',
        btnClass: 'btn-blue',
        keys: ['enter', 'shift'],
        action: function(){
            $.alert('Something else?');
        }
    }
}
});
```

I would like to make a beautiful shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confirm function only alerts a confirmed message, you should change

```
confirm: function () {
        $.alert('Confirmed!');
    },
```

to

```
confirm: function () {
            document.getElementById("kek").submit();
            $.alert('Confirmed!'); // may need to remove this
            
        },
```

Comment: Still does not submit the form after clicking submit

Comment: could you post the full code including the closing`</form>` tag and also your change your action to `action="?"` if submitting to the same page

Comment: action="" I'm empty here, and there is nothing else in the code except the closing tags. I am very young in programming, sorry if I do not understand the question correctly.

Comment: I mean your <form> tag where is it closed? and also where do you submit your form to, same file or another file?